# shadow not working on IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: html, css

Why this css not working on ie 7 and ie 8

```
.shadow
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.4s;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* For IE 8+ */
    zoom: 1;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#000000', Direction=145, Strength=3); /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [this](http://css3pie.com/) you can apply shadow.Check  it once

Comment: if you got the solution with my answer please accept this as answer